# What is the difference between angular js 2 starter project and CLI project

Tags: angular

i created angular js 2 project based on starter project (angular website) & another one based on CLI template project & i note the difference that there are more files in CLI template? what is the different between both and which one is preferred ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Quickstart is just for demo purposes, actually if you are gonna build a production app, you'll need to use the CLI, it is constantly improved and follows the style guide. Plus it comes with all in the box, you are ready to code, test and deploy with the CLI.